# ValueError: cannot use sparse input in 'SVC' trained on dense data

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm trying to run my classifier but I get this error

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

dataset = pd.read_csv('all_topics_limpo.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
data = pandas.get_dummies(dataset['verbatim_corrige'])
labels = dataset['label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

count_vector = CountVectorizer()
tfidf = TfidfTransformer()

classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 100))
#classifier = LogisticRegression()

train_counts = count_vector.fit_transform(X_train)
train_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(train_counts)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

test_counts = count_vector.transform(X_test)
test_tfidf = tfidf.transform(test_counts)
predicted = classifier.predict(test_tfidf)

predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)

print("confusion matrix")
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted, labels = labels))

print("F-score")
print(f1_score(y_test, predicted))
print(precision_score(y_test, predicted))
print(recall_score(y_test, predicted)) 

print("cross validation")
test_counts = count_vector.fit_transform(data)
test_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(test_counts)

scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(classifier, test_tfidf, labels, cv = 10)
print(scores)
print("Accuracy: {} +/- {}".format(scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

My output error:

> ValueError: cannot use sparse input in 'SVC' trained on dense data

I can not execute my code because of this problem and I am not understanding anything of what is happening.

**all output error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "classification.py", line 42, in 
>       predicted = classifier.predict(test_tfidf)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 584, in predict
>       Y = self.decision_function(X)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 614, in decision_function
>       for est, Xi in zip(self.estimators_, Xs)]).T
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 614, in 
>       for est, Xi in zip(self.estimators_, Xs)]).T
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 548, in predict
>       y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 308, in predict
>       X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 448, in _validate_for_predict
>       % type(self).**name**)
>
> ValueError: cannot use sparse input in 'SVC' trained on dense data

Comment: On which *exact* line does the error occur (since you define `predicted` 2 times in different ways)? Please include he full error trace.

Comment: Sorry, I add all output in my question

Comment: So, the error comes indeed from `classifier.predict(test_tfidf)`; check my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because your training & test data are not of the same kind: while you train in your initial `X_train` set:

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

you are trying to get predictions from a dataset which has undergone count vectorization & tf-idf transormations first:

```
predicted = classifier.predict(test_tfidf)
```

It is puzzling why you choose to do so, why you nevertheless compute `train_counts` and `train_tfidf` (you don't seem to actually use them anywhere), and why you are also trying to redefine `predicted` as `classifier.predict(X_test)` immediately afterwards. Normally, changing your training line to

```
classifier.fit(train_tfidf, y_train)
```

and getting rid of your second `predicted` definition should work OK...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
 test_tfidf = tfidf.transform(test_counts).toarray()
```

befor you want to predict your model and after :

```
predicted = classifier.predict(test_tfidf)
```

just do this simple code
nice job